# Принудительно закрыть все сокеты в Java

Tags: java-ee, glassfish, java, сокет

Имеется приложения flash AS3 клиент -- socket -- Java EJB модуль на сервере GlassFish.

Если соединение с одним или несколькими клиентами активно и я делаю undeploying этого EJB модуля, соединения как-то плохо обрываются и порт сервера остаётся открытым. И такая ситуация очень не нравится, потому что порт так и остаётся занятым до перезапуска GlassFish или всей виртуальной машины.

Ну и вопрос, естественно, **как принудительно закрыть все порты и сокеты при свёртывании модуля?**

Я даже не знаю, какой кусок кода выкладывать, ну вот, например:

**в EJB классе:**

```
@PreRemove
@PreDestroy
@PostRemove
private void Destroy() throws InterruptedException{
    Server.stopServer();
}
```

**В классе Server**

```
public static void stopServer(){
    IsActiveS = false;
    for(Server e : Connections){
        e.drop();
    }
    try {
        if(SeSocket!=null){
            if(!SeSocket.isClosed())
                SeSocket.close();
            SeSocket = null;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if(Settings.DEBUG)System.out.println("Error occured while closing socket: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

если переменная **IsActiveS** = false, то все циклы, которые есть в классе завершаются
**Connections** - список активных соединений
**IsActive** то же самое, что и **IsActiveS** только для одного экземпляра соединения

```
public void drop(){
    isActive = false;
    try {
        if(socket!=null){
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket.setSoTimeout(1);
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {}
    if(outStreamWriter!=null){
        try{
            outStreamWriter.close();
        }catch (Exception ex){}
        outStreamWriter = null;
    }
    if(inStreamReader!=null){
        try{
            inStreamReader.close();
        }catch (Exception ex){}
        inStreamReader = null;
    }
    if(socket!=null)socket = null;
    Connections.remove(this);
}
```

Comment: Так ваш "Destroy" вообще вызывается или нет? Попробуйте залоггировать его вызов и посмотрте И поправьте code convention, а то путаница получается. И разберитесь с методами закрытия, а то макароны какие-то получаются и явно много лишних действий делаете.

Comment: По поводу лишних действий - конечно, потом уберу - это от отчаяния :)

EJB аннотации @PreRemove, @PreDestroy, @PostRemove (ну хоть одна из них :-D) обязывают вызываться этот метод перед уничтожением бина. А при свёртывании приложения бин уничтожается, разве нет?

Comment: Только что проверил: вызывается один раз метод. Вероятно по @PreDestroy

Comment: А какой у вас бин? Вы уверены, что указатели на сокет != null ? Какой у вас бин: stateless или stateful ?

Comment: EJB класс, в котором вызываю destroy() у меня @Singleton, и, кстати, @Startup. Вопрос про сокет - где именно? У меня вроде везде проверки стоят. Каждому подключению в списке Connections соответствует Server со своим socket, так же есть один единственный SeSocket - статическая переменная ServerSocket, создаётся с самого начала

Comment: Так вот я про то и говорю.. если они null, то ничего не будет. Хотя, @Singleton по идее должен работать очень прозрачно..

Comment: Хм, ну я погляжу, но вообще код сервера у меня достаточно простой, да и я похоже показал все куски оттуда где я закрываю сокет или аннулирую ссылку на него, а создаётся он всегда вроде бы корректно.

Comment: мне вот интересно не существует ли какого-нибудь метода сказать глассфишу чтобы он закрыл определённый порт, открытый его приложением?..

Comment: Нет, такого метода нет и не может быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нашёл свою ошибку.
Закрыть порты извне не уничтожая сам GlassFish, конечно, невозможно.
И как оказалось, конечно, беда была в том, что нити Connections уничтожались до того, как успевали освободить свои сокеты. Поэтому я заставил главную нить ждать завершения остальных методом join().